# Display specific value in template file by putting specific condition on objects of array

Tags: angular, angular6

I have array of objects from which I want to display specific text on html file.

The conditions are:

1. If user subscribe then display text 'auto'
2. If user is not verified then text 'trial'
3. If user is verified and subscribed then text 'free'
4. If user subscription is over then text 'expired'
5. If user subscription is extended by admin then text 'manual'

For subscription I manage array called payment_details in database.
For verified manage boolean field called in database

I am unable to create condition for these on front end. So I tried in ts file. But it is taking last element of the array.

**template file:**

```
<tr class="table-rows-customized"  *ngFor="let therapist of therapistlist | filter : searchText" >
    <td class="td-data pointer" (click)="therapistdetails(therapist._id);">
         <img *ngIf="!therapist.profilepic" src="assets/img/users/user.jpg" class="user-image" alt="">
         <img *ngIf="therapist.profilepic" [src]="therapist.profilepic" class="user-image" alt="">
         {{ therapist.fullname }}
   </td>
   <td class="td-data">{{ type.id === therapist._id ? type.text : '' }} 
   </td>                             
</tr>
```

**ts file:**

```
 this.therapistlist.map((therapist) => {
   if(therapist.payment_details) {
     if(therapist.payment_details.length && therapist.verifiedBadge) {
              this.type = {
                text: 'free',
                id: therapist._id
              }
            }
            if(therapist.payment_details.length) {
              if(therapist.payment_details[0].paymentType == 'Cash') {
                this.type = {
                  text: 'manual',
                  id: therapist._id
                }
              }
              if(therapist.payment_details[0].paymentType == 'Credit Card') {
                this.type = {
                  text: 'auto',
                  id: therapist._id
                }
              }
            }
          }
          if(moment(therapist.premimumEndDate).isAfter(moment())) {
            this.type = {
              text: 'expired',
              id: therapist._id
            }
          }
        })
console.log('map.... ', this.type);
```

From above code I am not getting anything and in log I am getting null values.

Answer (score 0):

The .map function will go through each element in the array and calculate a type with your conditions. 
But your console.log is outside of the iterator, and it will always get the type for the last item in your array.

You need to assign and log, or use however you need, the type object inside the .map function. That way you will have the specific type for each of the objects in your initial array.

```
this.therapistlist.map((therapist) => {

    this.type = {
        id: therapist._id,
        text: 'default'       
    }

    if (therapist.payment_details) {
        if (therapist.payment_details.length && therapist.verifiedBadge) {
            this.type.text = 'free';
        } else if (therapist.payment_details.length) {
            if(therapist.payment_details[0].paymentType === 'Cash') {
                this.type.text = 'manual';
            } else if (therapist.payment_details[0].paymentType === 'Credit Card') {
                this.type.text = 'auto';
            }
        }
    }
    if (moment(therapist.premimumEndDate).isAfter(moment())) {
        this.type.text = 'expired';
    }

    console.log(this.type);
});
```

I have also refactored your code as one of the conditions was overlapping.

If this first condition was met, then the second one would also be met.

```
if(therapist.payment_details.length && therapist.verifiedBadge) 

if(therapist.payment_details.length)
```

Lastly as it is now if the subscription is expired it will always change the type no matter what the type was.

Comment: Thank you @Samuel for your answer. I just took your code and pasted in my code. I just get {id: "id of user", text: "default"} and it is printed up to array length..

Comment: @JaynaTanawala Ok, that means none of your conditions are being met. You should use more logs to debug and see why. You have to check the data in your array of objects.

Comment: Can't this possible on from end?